# $d : \Omega^r(R^n) \rightarrow Ω^{r+1}(R^n)$ show that: $d ◦ \phi^∗ = \phi^∗ ◦ d$

Tags: differential-forms, diffeomorphism, pullback

Let $U, V \subset R^n$ be two open sets and $\phi : V \rightarrow U $ a diffeomorphism.  For the outer derivative $d : \Omega^r(R^n) \rightarrow Ω^{r+1}(R^n)$ show that:
$$d ◦ \phi^∗ = \phi^∗ ◦ d.$$

What I thought to do:

Consider the operator $d' := (\phi^{-1})^∗ ◦ d ◦ \phi^∗ : \Omega^r(U) \rightarrow \Omega^{r+1}(U)$ and verify that:

- d' is linear
- $d'(\omega ∧ \eta) = d'\omega ∧ \eta + (-1)^{deg\omega} \omega ∧ d'\eta$
- Propriety of cocycle: $d'^2= d' ∘ d' =0$
- For $f\in \Omega^0(M)= F(M):d'f$ ist equal to the differential of the function $f$

So after that we can say that $d'= d$ then is $d ◦ \phi^∗ = \phi^∗ ◦ d$ verified. But I'm not sure how to prove these points and if my reasoning can make sense...

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ArcticChar I have tried to develop all the points by inserting d', but I can not get to the end, for example for the linearity I try to derivate d'

Comment: The last point should be easy to check? Please write down what you have tried and where you stuck in the post.